# Active Directory how to simulate a user login in and changin his password

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, active-directory, passwords

**Short story :**

Knowing the temporary password of a user, how to simulate a user login and change it's password without actually open a session when the option **user must change password at next logon** is enabled  ?

**Long story:**

I'm in a helpdesk and have access to an app that allow me to generate a new password for a AD user account. When the password is generated, the option user must change password is also activated. Sometimes the user is outside the office so he ask me to change the password for him. I'm able to switch user on my workstation, open a session with the user's temp password then change the pass.

*What I'd like is to make this password change from my own session.*

**What I have tried**

- *Run as*: `runas /user:domain cmd.exe` 
  -> error 1907 The user's password must be changed before logging on the first time.
- *net user* `net user username newpassword /dom` 
  -> error 5 access denied
- *start-process* `start-process -credential domain\username powershell.exe` 
  -> invalidOperationException  The user's password must be changed before logging on the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is really easy with the active directory module :

`Set-ADAccountPassword username`

will ask for the old and new password. That's all

Comment: Note that this does not update the lastLogon properties.